# What guru is telling people to pull up their toes when they deep squat?

Tags: squats

A month ago, I saw something new.  A guy was doing a deep squat mobility exercise, then he grabbed his toes from the front, and pulled up.  As a consequence of pulling on his toes, his lower back went into a deeper flexion.  Technically speaking, he was making an open chain exercise into a closed chain exercise.  I've been going to gyms for thirty years, and I've never seen anyone do this before.  Then I saw another person doing it, and then another person today, at the same gym.  My conclusion is that some fitness guru, probably on youtube, is telling people this is a good idea.  Does anybody know what fitness guru would be recommending you grab your toes during a deep squat?  Is it a crossfit thing?

Comment: It sounds more like a PT at your gym is telling people that.

Comment: @DeeV    Yea, I asked, and a trainer is recommending it.  The place has a few trainers, and I don't know which one this would be.   The question becomes, where is this trainer getting the idea from?   Most trainers get ideas for new exercises from celebrity fitness trainers.  I am wondering what  celebrity fitness trainer (guru) would recommend this?  Or maybe this is an original notion that popped into this trainers head.

Comment: I looked up "toe grab squats" and it seems to be a thing. There's a few Youtube videos on it and some fitness blogs talk about it. Seems to be for mobility, but less advanced people wouldn't be able to do it effectively. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_lbihu9L_c

Comment: I also have a book called "Olympic Weightlifting: A Complete Guide for Athletes & Coaches" which has a stretch they call (if I remember right) a "baby stretch" in which you squat down, put your arms between your legs, and grab your heels. Then push your hips down while in the pose.  It *really* stretches your hips and lower back. It also happens to be a yoga pose. I'm not sure if this is what the trainer is trying to do though.

Comment: @DeeV  Thanks for the video.  That is pretty much what I'm seeing.  At 1:39s in that video, this fitness model has very nice form.  His hips are open, his feet are turned out, his chest is high, his hands are cupping the front of his feet, and his lower back has almost no flexion.  This guy has some serious genetics.   However, at my gym where I have seen this, many of the clients are older, often overweight, and when they try this position, they don't look anything like this.  When they try this position, their chest is collapsed and their lower back is flexed to the end range of movement.